# Warning message when using pow() function in C programming language

Tags: c, pow

I am writing a very basic program to print the range of an **unsigned long long** variable in C language (0 to ((2 ^ n) - 1) where n is the number of bits for the data type in any system (with C installed in it and according to the compiler). In my system, the size of a long long variable is 8 bytes.

I am using the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned long long n;

   //n = pow(2, 63);
   //n = (n * 2) - 1;
     n = pow(2, 64) - 1;    

     printf("\nn: %llu\n", n);

     return 0;
}
```

upon compiling, gcc gives me the following error:

**Print_long_long_int.c:10:2: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow].**

On executing it, I get the correct output of 
n: 18446744073709551615

But, if I remove the single comments from the lines, and use them:

```
n = pow(2, 63);
n = (n * 2) - 1;
```

Instead of:

```
n = pow(2, 64) - 1;
```

It doesn't give me any such warning. And executes normally.
Why is this discrepancy happening?

Thanks!

Comment: It likely means GCC is not calling `pow()` at runtime but is evaluating the constant at compile time, and it notices that `pow(2, 64)` is too big to fit into a 64-bit unsigned integer, but doesn't refuse to complete the compilation and does manage to get the right answer by some more or less devious means.  Other compilers, or GCC with less optimization, might do things differently.

Comment: `pow` is simply not the right tool for the task, it works with `double` and not with integer types. So at any point you may loose precision. Use the shift operator `<<` to obtain large powers of `2`. But even then you obviously can't get a power higher then 63 if your type only has 64 bit.

Answer (score 3):

When you are giving

```
 pow(2,64) -1 ;
```

It exceeds the limit of unsigned long long. This is the reason you are getting that warning.

Range of unsigned long is `0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615`

Result of `pow(2,64)` is `18446744073709551616`.

Comment: If that be the case, why doe the lines: `n = pow(2, 63); n = (n * 2) - 1`; works? Because executing these two lines gives me the correct answer of **n: 18446744073709551615**. If the size of **unsigned long long** is lesser, shouldn't these two lines also pop up a warning message?

Answer (score 0):

Power should return an integer, and you're getting an unsigned long long. I just made a simple power function to handle unsigned long longs.

```
#include<stdio.h>

unsigned long long power(int base, int exponent)
{
    unsigned long long n = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < exponent ; i++)
        n *= base;

    return n;
}

int main()
{
unsigned long long n = power(2, 64) - 1; 
printf("n: %llu\n", n);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't **`unsigned long long n = 1`** (in the function definition of "power") because if it's 0, the overall product will compute to be 0.

Comment: Yes you're right. I was writing that in a hurry and made a careless mistake.